# How to run a Java program with external library from CLI

Tags: java

I am using IntelliJ for a Java project. My project structure looks something like this:

```
Crawler
    |----.idea
    |----lib
            jsoup-1.7.3.jar
    |----out
        |----production
            |----Crawler
                |----App
                    App.class
    |----src
        |----App
            App.java
    Crawler.iml
```

Now when I run the app from within IntelliJ, it loads the external lib and runs perfectly.

How should I run it from the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix (Linux, MacOS):

```
cd <path>/Crawler
java -cp out/production/Crawler:lib/jsoup-1.7.3.jar App.App
```

Windows:

```
cd <path>\Crawler
java -cp "out\production\Crawler;lib\jsoup-1.7.3.jar" App.App
```